# Retain spaces and extract cdata value in xml using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I hava a simple xml file,

```
  <root>
        <item1><![CDATA[Slement OF The Late Eleanor Sefton]]></item1>
        <item2>HEY        YOU</item2>
  </root>
```

and i wrote an xsl file to get these data,

```
     <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>

             <p> <xsl:value-of select="root/item1/text()" disable-output- 
               escaping="yes"/></p>


      </body>
      </html>
      </xsl:template>
```

I need to get the CDATA value [Slement OF The Late Eleanor Sefton] and maintain the space between HEY (with spacing)  YOU. I am not getting the expected output.Can i get some idea about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the target format is HTML where white space is collapsed I think this is not an XSLT problem but rather a question of using the right HTML element e.g.

```
<pre><xsl:value-of select="root/item2"/></pre>
```

will output

```
HEY        YOU
```

Comment: Thank you , it worked.I am using this <pre> for first time. But just want to be sure- Is this accepted in all kind of transform? or does this have any other defects.

Comment: `pre` is an HTML element, just like `p` or `div` or `table` so that has nothing to do with XSLT. As long as the target format is HTML, you can use `pre`. It usually is acompanied by a CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space setting like `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap`.

Comment: Neither XML parsing nor XSLT white space stripping would remove any spaces from input like `<item2>HEY        YOU</item2>` so there is nothing you need to retain explicitly there, the spaces are there and `<xsl:value-of select="item2"/>` outputs them, only depending on the result format and its rendering rules you might not see them.

Comment: yes, but i can see the font style varies from other outputs to this, so asked.